# Gerrit push tags in packed-refs

Tags: git, tags, gerrit

We have 2 gerrit sites. 
When trying to pull one of the repositories from gerrit site A to my local laptop, and push my local repository to gerrit site B, I meet a problem.
For gerrit site A I have successfully cloned the repository, and for gerrit site B, I have set up the repository access as:

```
Reference:refs/tags/*
Push 
Allow Administrators  Force Push
Push Annotated Tag
Allow Administrators  Force Push
```

When trying to use command `git push <remote repo> --tags`
I get errors like `[remote rejected] <tag name> -> <tag name> (prohibited by Gerrit)`

After check the local repository `.git` folder, I found that all tags are stored in `.git/packed-refs` and there is nothing in `refs/tags` folder

I am not sure if the push command is trying to create the `packed-refs` file in the repository of gerrit site B?
Is there any way I can do to handle this situation? Have to unpack the `packed-refs` to `refs/tags` folder and then push again?

Comment: Is `remote repo` in the command the url to Site B's repository?

Comment: It's the remote repo alias, like `origin`, here we use `dest`

Comment: Does `dest` point to a Site B's repository? Is the username in the group Administrators?

Comment: Yes, the `dest` point to the site B repository, and the user I am using is in the group Administrator. Actually, for other options are working fine, like to create tag in site B and fetch it to local repository (this tag will be created under local repository `.git/refs/tags`)

Comment: grant the right `Create Reference` to Administrators.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Finally I resolved the issue by add `Forge Committer Identity` right in `refs/tags/*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to unpack the packed-refs to refs/tags folder.

The "prohibited by Gerrit" is a general error message that is returned by Gerrit if a push is not allowed. In your case, probably, this is happening due to one of these:

- You pushed an annotated tag without 'Create Annotated Tag' access
  right on refs/tags/*
- You pushed a signed tag without 'Create Signed Tag' access right on
  refs/tags/*
- You pushed a lightweight tag without the access right 'Create
  Reference' for the reference name refs/tags/*
- You pushed a tag with somebody else as tagger and you don’t have the
  'Forge Committer' access right for the reference name refs/tags/*

See more info about this error [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/error-prohibited-by-gerrit.html).

Comment: Cool, before I already have the `Create Reference` right in `refs/tags/*` but not works. Then I follow your advice and add `Forge Committer Identity` right in `refs/tags/*` and it works now. Thanks very much.